# Read from .txt File and store specific lines in strings

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

I have a text document looking like this:

```
#Something
info1
#Something
info2
#Something
info3
```

Now I want to read this file and skip all lines starting with `#` and store the normal strings in a `char` array.

I tried this:

```
void ReadFromFile()
{
    char *info1;
    char *info2;
    char *info3;
    char str[200];
    int line1;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("game:\\Config.txt", "r");
    if(!fp)
        return;
    while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),fp) != NULL)
    {
        line1++;
        int len = strlen(str)-1;
        if(str[len] == '\n')
            str[len] = 0;
        printf("%i", line1);
        if(line1 == 2)
        {
            printf("%s", str);
            info1 = str;
        }
        if(line1 == 4)
        {
            printf("%s", str);
            info2 = str;
        }
        if(line1 == 6)
        {
            printf("%s", str);
            info3 = str;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n", info1);
    printf("%s\n", info2);
    printf("%s\n", info3);
}
```

When I run this I get the output:

```
1
2info1
3
4info2
5
6info3

info3
info3
info3
```

Any idea why this is not working? I want the output to be:

```
1
2info1
3
4info2
5
6info3

info1
info2
info3
```

Comment: all your pointers ( info1, info2, info3 ) point to the points to the same location ( str ) and so you are ending up with the final value entered in str ("info3")

Comment: and how would i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these pointers:

```
char *info1;
char *info2;
char *info3;
```

point to the same buffer (each write through these pointers will overwrite the previous contents):

```
char str[200];
```

You'll have to make three separate buffers:

```
char str1[200];
char str2[200];
char str3[200];
```

Or:

```
char str[3][200];

while(int i = 0; fgets(str[i], sizeof(*str), fp) != NULL; )
{
    // increment i if line without # was read
}
```

Or print the lines immediately after reading them (only one buffer required).

Comment: and how would i write the string from the textdocument onto those?

Comment: You could use `strcpy`

Comment: @N.W.A Added an example with a 2D array.